# I am editing the zoom of my entire react app, but when I do it the modal (material ui) breaks

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
<div style={{zoom:"85%"}}> 
 <myApp>
<div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7UgI.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this or know another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<div style={{transform:"scale(1.85)"}}> 
 <myApp>
<div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp

Comment: try to add the myApp component